# Using a HTM file for an Outlook Signature

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I have been messing with e-mail signatures and have become stuck.

My original e-mail signature used "a href" and pointed to an image which was locally stored on my c drive, this then attached the image to the bottom of the e-mails and embedded the image as users receiving would also be able to see it.

Since this I have tried to make a nicer looking e-mail signature which uses three locally hosted images and although when sending it looks fine my end, users receiving cannot see the images.....

I can get it to work if I host the images but was wondering if there's a way to do it with the images being locally stored on my PC?

Here is the e-mail signature code I'm trying to get working, when opening the htm file it looks correct, as well as at the point of sending the e-mail.

I'm using Office 365.

Thanks!

```
<HTML>
<br><style=font-family:CorpoS" style="font-size:  12pt;";><FONT color=#000000 face="CorpoS">Kind regards,</FONT>
<b><p style=font-family:CorpoS" style="font-size:  14pt;";><FONT color=#000000 face="CorpoS">FirstName</FONT></p></b><br>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<BODY style="font-size: 10pt; font-family:CorpoS, sans-serif;">
<table style="width:530px; font-size:10pt; font-family:Arial, sans-serif;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size:10pt; width:180px; padding-right:10px; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle"><p style="margin-bottom:30px; line-height:1.2">
<b><style=font-family:CorpoS" style="font-size:  12pt;";><FONT color=#003bff face="CorpoS">FirstName LastName</FONT><br style="line-height: 10px" /></b>
<style=font-family:Tahoma" style="font-size:  9pt;";><FONT color=#000000 face="Tahoma">Job Title</FONT>
</p><a href="https://www.companysite.co.uk" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <img border="0" alt="logo" width="143" style="width:143px; height:auto; border:0;" src="C:/SignatureImage/Logo.png"></a></td>
<td style="font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif; padding-left:15px; vertical-align:top; line-height:1.2; border-left:solid 2px #cccccc" valign="top">
<span style="font-family:CorpoS" style="font-size:  9.5pt;";><FONT color=#000000 face="CorpoS">Mobile</span><br>
<span style="font-family:CorpoS" style="font-size:  9.5pt;";><FONT color=#000000 face="CorpoS">Landline</span><br>
<span style="font-family:CorpoS" style="font-size:  9.5pt;";><FONT color=#000000 face="CorpoS">E-Mail Address</span><br>
<span><strong><a href="http://www.companysite.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="font-size:9pt; font-family:CorpoS, sans-serif; color:#003bff;">www.companysite.com</span></a></strong></span>   
<p style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px">
<span><a href="https://www.facebook.com/company" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="15" alt="facebook icon" style="border:0; height:30px; width:30px; " src="https://www.company.com/img/social/facebook.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/company" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="15" alt="linkedin icon" style="border:0; height:30px; width:30px; " src="https://www.company.com/img/social/linked-in.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://twitter.com/company" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="15" alt="twitter icon" style="border:0; height:30px; width:30px; " src="https://www.company.com/img/social/twitter.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/company" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="15" alt="youtube icon" style="border:0; height:30px; width:30px; " src="https://www.company.com/img/social/youtube.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.instagram.com/company/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="15" alt="instagram icon" style="border:0; height:30px; width:30px; " src="https://www.company.com/img/social/instagram.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<a href="https://www.company.com/offers/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration:none;"><img alt="banner" width="257" style="width:300px; height:auto; border:0;" border="0"  src="c:/SignatureImage/Signature.jpg"></a>
</p></span></td></tr></tbody></table>
<img src="c:/SignatureImage/Special.png" width="475"> <b><style=font-family:CorpoS" style="font-size: 12pt;";><br><br>
<a href="http://www.company.com/group-policies.aspx"><style="font-family:CorpoS" style="font-size: 12pt;><FONT face="CorpoS">Click here to view our Privacy Notice</FONT></a><br>
<p style="text-align: center; width:525px; border: 1px solid red"><Font Size=2 face=Arial color=red><b><u>Cyber Crime</b></u><br>Please be aware that there is a significant risk posed by cyber fraud, specifically affecting email accounts and bank account details. <BR><B>PLEASE NOTE</B> Our bank account details WILL NOT change during the course of a transaction and we WILL NOT notify you of any change to our bank account details via email. <br> Please check account details with us in person if in any doubt. We will not accept responsibility if you transfer money into an incorrect account.</font>
<br>
<p style= "text-align: left; width:525px"><Font Size=1 face=Arial color=black>Company <BR>This electronic transmission and any attachments are confidential and must not be made available to anyone other than the intended addressee. <BR>If you receive this communication in error, please tell us as soon as possible. <BR>Please note that, whilst we try to ensure that attachments are virus-free, we cannot accept responsibility for situations where this is not the case.<BR>We do not authorise the making of any contracts via the Internet. <BR>Company Limited.<BR></FONT></p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the desktop version, please check if you have the following button while editing your signature. [image]

Otherwise, [here](https://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/how-to-insert-images-into-office-365-email-signatures/) is a guide for the web browser version.

Comment: Hi Samuel, I was trying to create the signature as a htm file, but I followed your advice and then opened the file to see what code it used, i've now managed to copy this for any additional images too and yes they do stay embedded in the email when the recipient views it! So many thanks this solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else reading,

If you use one image then you can link to a local folder on your PC in one of the c: folders.

If you use more than one image it's possible but becomes very difficult with resolutions etc.

I ended us using hosted images for the outlook signatures and should have done this sooner, much easier to arrange etc!

Thanks